# error del analizador: No se pudo cargar el tipo 'ControlArriendos.Mantencion.Informes.InformeTecnicos.aspx'

Tags: html, c#, sql-server, asp.net

Contexto:
Estoy tratando de generar un informe sobre "Técnicos" pero al momento de hacer clic para que me muestre este formulario me arroja este error

```
Error del analizador
Descripción: Error al analizar el recurso requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error de análisis específicos y modifique el archivo de código fuente en consecuencia.

Mensaje de error del analizador: No se pudo cargar el tipo 'ControlArriendos.Mantencion.Informes.InformeTecnicos.aspx'.

Error de código fuente:


Línea 1:  
Línea 2:  
Línea 3:  

Archivo de origen: /Consultas/Informes/InformeTecnicos.aspx    Línea: 1
```

Mi codigo es:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="InformeTecnicos.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlArriendos.Mantencion.Informes.InformeTecnicos.aspx" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <table style="width:100%; height: 405px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 413px">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" style="float:right" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/iconos/atras.png" Height="63px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Width="86px" />

            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" style="width: 982px">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="956px" BackColor="#99FFCC" BorderStyle="Groove" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" LinkDisabledColor="Red">
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 413px; height: 212px;"></td>
            <td style="height: 212px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 413px; height: 37px;"></td>
            <td style="height: 37px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="datasetguiaTableAdapters.CE_ObtenerTecnicos_JP"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Primero intenta haciendo un rebuild al proyecto, si no cambia CodeBehind por CodeFile

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InformeTecnicos.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlArriendos.Mantencion.Informes.InformeTecnicos.aspx" %>
```

o revisa que la definición de tu clase esté marcada como pública

```
namespace EspaciodeNombres {
  public class Clase {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: En el proyecto hay mas informes y funcionan correctamente con el "CodeBehind" así que creo que no es problema de eso, además, verifique que la clase este marcada como publica, así que no se la verdad por que persiste el error